# Looking for a simple alert of prompt() variable as string or as a number

Tags: javascript

My search is very simple , i am looking to set a `prompt()` variable , then check if typeof variable is string then alert ("this is string "), else if is a number then alert is a number otherwise alert something else .
I've tried this and it doesn't work...

```
var text = prompt("enter your name");

if(typeof text === "number"){

    alert("this is not a number");
}
 else if(typeof text ==="string"){

    alert("this is a string");                          

}
else{

    alert("anyway.. thanks to try");

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The type of the return value from `prompt()` will always be either a String if the user enters a response (even if it's blank, or looks like a number), or `null` if the user cancels the dialog. It is never a Number.

If you want to find out if the user entered a string that can be *interpreted* as a number, that's another matter entirely. Consider:

```
if (!isNaN(parseFloat(text))) {
    alert("it's a number");
}
```

(But note that there are some caveats associated with `parseFloat()`; in particular, it will ignore trailing junk. `123.45xyz` is parsed as `123.45`, for example.)

Answer (score 2):

Use double equal signs instead of triple equal signs and when checking typeof, use brackets around the object you are checking. Also, it is a good idea to use else if on your second condition.

Answer (score 2):

Your first statement should be "This is a number". Prompt() will return the value as a string, so the first condition will always be false. You can change the condition to use isNan(text) instead. You first condition with the rest of the code can look like this and should work. You will probably never hit the last condition.

```
var text = prompt("enter your name");
if (!isNaN(text)) {
    alert("this is a number");
} else if (typeof text === "string") {
    alert("this is a string");
} else {
    alert("anyway.. thanks to try");
}
```

Comment: Looks like @duskwuff below saw the same thing and posted a more thorough answer first while I was testing the code for mine. :)

Comment: Your first line is incorrect - much as I prefer treating `typeof` as a function, it's actually an operator (similar to `sizeof` in C/C++). It doesn't require parentheses around its argument.